# File that normally opens our application, but will fall back to Excel

Tags: excel, file-extension, spreadsheetml

Our application exports snippets of databases in XLSX format. We wrote our own code on top of  `System.Packaging` as it is many (many!) times faster than using the Excel objects.

Right now we save these files with a .xlsx format, and that works OK. However, it would be much nicer if double-clicking one of these opened our app instead, but failed back to Excel on machines without it.

I know that SpreadsheetML has a feature to do this. If you insert this near the top of the file:

```
<?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?>
```

some sort of magic occurs that causes Excel to open on Win machines. While this might work in SML files, it does not appear to work in "real" xlsx files - I tried adding this line to various parts of the workbook structure but it remained unrecognized.

So is there a similar mechanism we can use in "true" XLSX files generated by System.Packaging? Or some other Windows mechanism we should use in these situations?

Comment: Could you create a windows service that monitors a user opening a file (or triggers when new instances of Excel are created), end the Excel process and create a new instance of your program?

Definitely not the most glamorous approach but I can't think of anything similar to the feature suggested above offered by Excel

Comment: That would require the file to retain the .xlsx extension, so how would I know it came from our app? It also seems very heavyweight. Is there no general way to define a backup editor?

Comment: Oh sorry, I realize I forgot to mention this part: my idea is to change the file extension to something associated with our app, like ".thisfile".That still works for ODF/SML files, as the internal progid redirects it to Excel.

Comment: Ah right, I'm with you now. Hm, as far as I know I don't think there's anything that Windows offers that lets you specify a 'backup' program to use which is what I think you're looking for (correct me if I'm wrong!). The only way I can think of it so associate the file type with a batch/script file or a 'middle-man' program that can determine whether or not your app is installed. And if not, launch Excel. However, it sounds like you don't want a dependency like this.